# How do I get WebDAV working?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, https, webdav

I'm running 2008r2 and have IIS 7 installed along with the necessary WebDAV Publishing roles/features.

I can connect internally within my LAN via mapping a network drive, providing credentials, then connecting. Outside my LAN from my home, I cannot do the same thing.

The odd thing is if I go to:

```
https://domain_ip
```

in a browser, I get prompted for my credentials, and I see a listing of my files.

Why does this not work remotely? I have a feeling I am missing something extremely minor; but being as this is my first time doing this, I don't know what that would be.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Windows provides two WebDAV clients: Web Folders and WebDAV Mini Redirector. The clients are integrated and come preinstalled with your Windows.

### Web Folders (XP only)

The first generation WebDAV client provided by Microsoft is called Web Folders and allows one to drag and drop between a remote WebDAV server and your local computer. The Web Folders client provides functionality similar to (secure) FTP.

How to connect (XP only):

1. Go to My Network Places, and click on Add Network Place at the top of the left sidebar.
2. The window that pops up is the Add Network Place Wizard. Click Next.
3. On the next page, enter the URL of the WebDAV folder in the box named Internet or network address and click Next.
4. A window asking for your username and password will pop up at this point. Enter your username and password, and click OK.
5. On the next page, enter a name for this share -- this is the name that will show up in the My Network Places listing.
6. Click Finish on the next page.

### WebDAV Mini Redirector (XP, Vista, and Win7)

The second generation Microsoft WebDAV client is called WebDAV Mini Redirector and allows one to map a WebDAV location to a Drive letter the same way as if you were using a Windows File Sharing/SMB/CIFS share.

How to connect:

1. Right click on My Computer and select Map Network Drive.
2. In the Folder "entry field", enter the URL, and click Finish.
3. Enter your username and password in the authentication box that
   appears.

#### WebDAV Mini Redirector limitations:

- No support for secure connections (HTTPS) on Windows XP.
- There is support on Windows 7, but it does not always work. It is inconsistent.
- Your WebDAV server must be using port 80, the default port.
- Typically fails when transfering larger files.
- Gets confused if the user does not have access to read and/or write to a file or directory.

Comment: I thought the idea behind WebDAV was to put all of these over SSL/HTTPS; do I still need to open those ports? I'll try this later today or tonight and report back, thanks.

Comment: miss understood your question, fixing answer

Comment: John: So this is basically broken? Then how am I able to say, connect to my hosted Sharepoint by going to https://whatever.hostedsharepoint.com and giving it my credentials? Am I missing something (other than ports)? I saw one guide mentioning installing the Desktop Experience service on the server and ensuring the WebClient service is running. But I really don't feel like taking down a box like this just for something that trivial that I've only seen in one guide, and one guide only...

Comment: Are you using the Webfolders or WebDAV Mini redirector?  also what OS are you running at home?

Comment: I'm guessing the WebDAV mini-redirectory; I don't see any options for that in IIS 7, it's just to enable, or disable WebDAV. OS at home is Windows 7 Pro. :\